# What all should I delete before uploading a laravel project?

Tags: laravel, web-hosting

My laravel project contains:- 28,408 files and its size is:- 169.4MB

 Apart from default my packages are:-

```
"laravel/ui": "^2.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "3.0",
        "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "^3.0"
```

I can only upload 10000 files, what should I do?

 As this is my first time uploading any website online it would really help if your answer is in simple manner

*-ThankYou*

Comment: Where/how are you uploading the files? Are you including the `node_modules` directory as well?

Comment: uploading it on the live server (hosting), yes i haven't deleted anything not even node modules. should i delete them and if yes then how?

Comment: How are you uploading them i.e. are you using FTP, are you creating a zip of your application, etc.? What hosting are you using for your application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying a `Laravel` package you should leave out `vendor`, `storage` and `node_modules`.

Then run these scripts on the server to build the dependencies. These needs to be installed on your server.

```
npm install

composer install --no-dev
```

This should highly decrease the amount of files you upload.

Comment: Why the `storage` directory?

Comment: Storage should be dependent on your server and is normally gitignore for that reason. It's the local storage for users to upload images to or similar, that should have nothing to do with your local environment.

If you want static files or similar, that is deployed put them in resources.

Comment: A helper for figuring out what should not to be uploaded is to look at the gitignore from the framework https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.gitignore

Comment: okhay so all i have to do is delete  the storage folder, vendor folder and node_modules folder from my project and find where i can run commands on my server

Comment: No deletion, just not upload them. Usually you deploy your project by cloning from github, where these files are already ignored and building the project from scratch.

Comment: @mrhn so I will not upload those folders, but the github link that you have shared, in that here are many more folders mentioned which are not meant to be uploaded, should i remove them aswell?

Comment: it depends, in the perfect world yes, but since you are uploading this as you are. It is probably not as critical. Another solution is to clone the project from git and upload that, i assume you are using git. If you remove these 3 folders i would guess you would have a way smaller project and able to upload it